# Windows Phone: how to handle an event from a web page in a WebView?

Tags: events, webview, event-handling, windows-phone, handler

Which callback/delegate is the one to intercept the event of a user clicking on a link within a WebView?
I'd want that URL. I just need to know if it is possible and how should I do in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch events triggered by Javascript code with [ScriptNotify event described here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx)

Not sure what you really want to do but this might be a starting point for you.

Comment: example: if the web view shows this question and the user clicks on your link, I'd like to get that URL, as a string

Comment: this isn't a js but simply a href

Comment: Webview has NavigationStarting event , I don't have environment to test it but I think that event will trigger when Webiew tries to load a new content.